# How to refresh terminal page in C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal

I am developing a text adventure game, with menu screen similar to this

```
******************************
|      Hello, Adventurer     |
|                            |
|     What is your name?     |
******************************
Name:
```

And so the curser would blink at the name. But when the player types the name it will show like this

Now lets say for example I typed "John" as a name

```
******************************
|         Hello, John        |
|                            |
|     Welcome to Text-RPG    |
******************************
```

But then it would print the above text in a separate section.

Is it possible to replace the first text set with the second text set Without having it separate section ?

Comment: So you are using the curses library, yes?

Comment: what do you mean by "curses library"? @trojanfoe

Comment: Well time to start searching.

Comment: I would say you need to either use a terminal control library like `ncurses` or else provide a *scrolling* interface. You *can* send control codes to the terminal directly but that is fiddly and not very portable.

Comment: Well right now I'm using the Mac terminal to run my programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OSX Terminal, you can use so-called "ANSI escape sequences", including these:

```
\033[2J
\033[H
```

which respectively *clear* the screen and *move* the cursor to the "home" position (the upper-left corner).  If you are writing a simple program which prints some information and then prompts for input, it works reasonably well to repaint the whole screen between prompts.  The `top` program does something like this:

```
cout << "\033[2J\033[H";
```

Most terminals do not clear the display when you send a form-feed (`'\f'` or `^L`), because most are based on VT100 emulation.  OSX Terminal is not one of those rare exceptions to the rule.

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when I type control/L?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_form_feed)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using graphics in your game? If yes, you can play with frames to be displayed at what time to the user But if you are a beginner than may be you don't have a very accurate solution to your problem right now. However, There is a simple trick which could work in your case.

1. After displaying your first box, you can print a lot of empty spaces, like a big block of empty spaces which may give user an illusuion that fiirst box has disappeared but obviously this will bring your scroll bar to scroll down.
2. Do you have any idea of bash sripting? If yes then make use of "clear" command in your coding file. Something related to this

Comment: No, I am making a **text** RPG game

Answer (score 0):

`putchar('\f');` will clear the screen in most terminals.

This just sends a "form-feed" character (12 for ASCII terminals, which is <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>), which clears the screen.

Comment: Ok, so, where do I put the `putchar('\f');`?

Comment: That will clear the screen, but not necessarily move the cursor.  OP likely expects the printout to "stay" in the same place.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: the question is not very clear, but it sounds like the OP just wants to clear the current screen and display something new. Who knows, though ? If he needs something fancier than that then ncurses is probably the way to go...

Comment: @RapidReverse: just add that line at the point in the program where you want to clear the screen, e.g. after you've read the response from the user.

Comment: @PaulR it still doesn't clear the screen somehow. I can still see the first text set above the second text set.

Comment: Are you talking about the Xcode console or the OS X Terminal ? It should work for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.You can try the logic of displaying newlines as follows
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void clear_scr()
{
    /*printing 100 new lines to clear everything on screen*/
    cout << string( 100, '\n' ); 
}
int main()
{  
    cout << "Clearning Screen" << endl;
    clear_scr();
    cout<<"SCREEN CLEARED"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

2. I have seen this code on various websites. This might work but i am not sure about it. Try it.

In Windows:

#include <cstdlib>

int main() { 
    std::system("cls");
    return 0;
}
In Linux/Unix:

#include <cstdlib>

int main() { 
    std::system("clear");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First clear the screen using `system("CLS")` and them print the new screen using the name of the player like you want`cout << "Hello, " << playerName << endl;`

Comment: This is a very poor and non-portable solution, which only works on DOS/Windows - OP is using Mac OS X.